# Rails 4 deeply nested content tags and strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I've been banging my head against the wall with view helpers, concatenation, safe buffers etc for ages, usually I manage to muddle my way through but this time i'm stumped.

The following is taken from my test results, and should give you a clear example of what I am trying to output.

ACTUAL

```
<ul><li class="bold-weight up-c disabled-toilet"><div class="center"><span class="icon"></span></div></li></ul>
```

EXPECTED

```
<ul><li class="bold-weight up-c disabled-toilet"><div class="center"><span class="icon"></span></div>Disabled toilet
```

So the only thing I can't output is "Disabled toilet" (which comes in dynamically any way) within the li tag but after the closing inner div tag.

You can see from the method 'accessability_sub_level' where I am trying achieve this.

```
  def venue_accessability(venue)
    return unless venue.get_accessability.any?
    content_tag(:ul, nil) do
      venue.get_accessability.map do |va|
        accessability_sub_level(va)
      end.join().html_safe
    end
  end

  private

  def accessability_sub_level(va)
    content_tag(:li, nil, class: "bold-weight up-c #{va[:icon]}") do
      content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'center') do
        concat content_tag(:span, nil, class: 'icon')
      end
      va[:title]
    end
  end
```

Help most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in `accessability_sub_level` is that you are only returning `va[:title]` from the first `content_tag` block. You have to concatenate it with the nested `content_tag` block:

```
def accessability_sub_level(va)
  content_tag(:li, nil, class: "bold-weight up-c #{va[:icon]}") do
    content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'center') do
      content_tag(:span, nil, class: 'icon')
    end.concat(va[:title])
  end
end
```

(This is hard to test/reproduce for me so this might not be a complete solution, it might not even work at all...)